# has no method 'focus' on ui-bootstrap datepicker

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, focus, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm getting this error:

```
TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'focus'
```

when I do click on datepicker input. I'm using:

- angular v1.0.8
- angular-bootstrap v0.5

This [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/O4e7olMaaPw2HcSpxvxK) shows that error

Comment: Looks like the jQuery Lite that Angular bundles doesn't have the element.focus() method. When I included the full jQuery library within your plunker the error goes away. Looks like a bug with the ui-bootstrap code since they claim you don't need to include the ful jQuery library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a bug in AngularJS that was making the directive failing with the error described here. We did a work-around in angular-ui/bootstrap in 0.6.0. If you include the lates version of angular-ui/bootstrap (0.6.0) things work as expected:
http://plnkr.co/edit/3pltZkZ7deNfYKVb72FY?p=preview